# KALMAN filter doesn't respond to changes

Tags: filter, filtering, kalman-filter, pykalman

I am implementing a **Kalman filter** for the first time to get voltage values from a source.  It works and it stabilizes at the source voltage value but if then the source changes the voltage the filter doesn't adapt to the new value.

I use 3 steps:

1. Get the Kalman gain

   ```
   KG = previous_error_in_estimate / ( previous_error_in_estimate + Error_in_measurement )
   ```
2. Get current estimation

   ```
   Estimation = previous_estimation + KG*[measurement - previous_estimation]
   ```
3. Calculate the error in estimate

   ```
   Error_in_estimate = [1-KG]*previous_error_in_estimate
   ```

The thing is that, as  0 <= KG <= 1, Error_in_estimate decreases more and more and that makes KG to also decrease more and more ( **`error_in_measurement`** is a constant ), so at the end **the estimation only depends on the previous estimation and the current measurement is not taken into account**.

This prevents the filter from adapt himself to measurement changes.

How can I do to make that happen?

Thanks

---

### EDIT:

Answering to Claes:

I am not sure that the Kalman filter is valid for my problem since I don't have a system model, I just have a bunch of readings from a quite noisy sensor measuring a not very predictable variable.

To keep things simple, imagine reading a potentiometer ( a variable resistor ) changed by the user, you can't predict or model the user's behavior.

I have implemented a very basic SMA ( Simple Moving Average ) algorithm and I was wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Is the Kalman filter valid for a problem like this?

If not, what would you suggest?

**2ND EDIT**

Thanks to Claes for such an useful information

I have been doing some numerical tests in MathLab (with no real data yet) and doing the convolution with a Gaussian filter seems to give the most accurate result.

[image: Kalman measurement variance R=0.1^2 Bad result]

With the Kalman filter I don't know how to estimate the process and measurement variances, is there any method for that?. Only when I decrease quite a lot the measurement variance the kalman filter seems to adapt. In the previous image the measurement variance was R=0.1^2 (the one in the original example). This is the same test with R=0.01^2

[image: Kalman measurement variance R=0.01^2 Better result]

Of course, these are MathLab tests with no real data. Tomorrow I will try to implement this filters in the real system with real data and see if I can get similar results

Comment: Please provide your code or system model/parameters, it is difficult to analyze your problem without them.

Comment: @ClaesRolen thanks for your reply, please, read the edited post

Comment: The model of the system in my answer was the simplest possible. it was predicting the next value to be the same as the previous. An improvement would be to set the prediction to be: x(n+1) = x(n)+drift+acceleration, but then we need to rewrite the code to support matrix ...

Answer (score 1):

A simple MA filter is probably sufficient for your example. If you would like to use the Kalman filter there is a great example at the [SciPy cookbook](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/KalmanFiltering.html)

I have modified the code to include a step change so you can see the convergence.

```
# Kalman filter example demo in Python
# A Python implementation of the example given in pages 11-15 of "An
# Introduction to the Kalman Filter" by Greg Welch and Gary Bishop,
# University of North Carolina at Chapel Hill, Department of Computer
# Science, TR 95-041,
# http://www.cs.unc.edu/~welch/kalman/kalmanIntro.html

# by Andrew D. Straw

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10, 8)

# intial parameters
n_iter = 400
sz = (n_iter,) # size of array
x1 = -0.37727*np.ones(n_iter/2) # truth value 1
x2 = -0.57727*np.ones(n_iter/2) # truth value 2
x = np.concatenate((x1,x2),axis=0)
z = x+np.random.normal(0,0.1,size=sz) # observations (normal about x, sigma=0.1)

Q = 1e-5 # process variance

# allocate space for arrays
xhat=np.zeros(sz)      # a posteri estimate of x
P=np.zeros(sz)         # a posteri error estimate
xhatminus=np.zeros(sz) # a priori estimate of x
Pminus=np.zeros(sz)    # a priori error estimate
K=np.zeros(sz)         # gain or blending factor

R = 0.1**2 # estimate of measurement variance, change to see effect

# intial guesses
xhat[0] = 0.0
P[0] = 1.0

for k in range(1,n_iter):
    # time update
    xhatminus[k] = xhat[k-1]
    Pminus[k] = P[k-1]+Q

    # measurement update
    K[k] = Pminus[k]/( Pminus[k]+R )
    xhat[k] = xhatminus[k]+K[k]*(z[k]-xhatminus[k])
    P[k] = (1-K[k])*Pminus[k]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(z,'k+',label='noisy measurements')
plt.plot(xhat,'b-',label='a posteri estimate')
plt.plot(x,color='g',label='truth value')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Estimate vs. iteration step', fontweight='bold')
plt.xlabel('Iteration')
plt.ylabel('Voltage')
```

And the output is:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Claes for the example, it has been very useful. You can see some results in my edited post.